# Determining for what values is a system of inequalities true.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of inequalities:

\begin{equation}
8A^2\alpha+44A\alpha+60\alpha>3A^2\alpha^2+12A^2+18A\alpha^2+40A+27\alpha^2+40 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A > 0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alpha > 1 \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Is there a procedure that determines for what value range(s) of $\alpha$ inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisifed?

UPDATE: Instead of determining whether it is true/false, wanted to figure out for what range(s) of values of $\alpha$ is the system of inequalities true. If $(1$) and $(2)$ is true for $\alpha \le 1$ then that will mean no solution exists.

UPDATE 2: This is just an algebra problem at this point. Testing at $\alpha = 1$ is false and finding when RHS is equal to LHS has no solution for $\alpha > 1$. Therefore there does not exist an $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: You don't need any algorithm. If you compute LHS - RHS, you will notice when $A, \alpha$ are very large, the difference is dominated by the term $-3A^2\alpha^2$ and is negative. This means the inequality must fail for large $A,\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=1$ and $\alpha=2$, then the left side is $224$ and the right side is $284$. So the inequality is false.

Comment: That is basically sampling on the domain of possible values and testing it. Is there a way without sampling? Not trial and error but a algorithm that will solve this.

Comment: @JohnKarasev You need to define 'algorithm'. For instance, what is the difference between an algorithm which just plugs in values and one that does whatever it is you are thinking? Both are algorithms. So you need to be more specific. Certainly there are some in special cases, like is $x^2>2x-1$ because this is $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2>0$ for $x \neq 1$ and you can have a factoring algorithm that will tell you this. But of course, that is problem specific and you still need to program the knowledge that $-^2>0$ for $- \neq 0$.

Comment: @JohnKarasev Generally, you want everything over to one side and then you are testing if $->0$ for whatever $-$ is. If it is a general polynomial in $n$ variables, this almost becomes equivalent to testing if $-=0$, which it depends on the context whether an algorithm *exists*. Even if an algorithm exists, you still need to find it. There will be no (I believe) general algorithm which will tell you. Most algorithms will still need some evaluation, such as evaluating derivatives. But does this violate your 'simulations'?

Comment: @JohnKarasev Again, the problem as stated is a bit ill-posed, even if I and most others will understand what you are hoping for. In any case, the questions was is this inequality true, and as I showed, it is not. If you wanted to know generally, that would be a different question, and you should then create a new one to ask. I would be interested in others answers as well! But be specific in asking, e.g. is there an algorithm which gives 'T/F' if $F(x,y)>0$ is true over the reals where $F(x,y)$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: I see. Just realized that I was asking not the right thing, the question is updated.

Comment: here is the updated question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677188/given-system-of-inequalities-how-to-determine-for-what-range-of-values-they-are please take a look

Comment: @JohnKarasev Thank you for posting as a separate question, and it's certainly one I'd be interested in hearing answers for. +1 But sadly, it's out of my area of expertise. Unless you were only interested in integer/rational solutions, in which case I can tell you almost certainly, no. No such general algorithm exists.

Answer (score 1):

LHS is $\alpha (8A^2 + 44A+60)$ and RHS is $\alpha^2(3A^2 +18A + 27) +(12A^2 +40A + 40)$.  And as all components are positive:

So $\alpha (8A^2 + 44A+60) >  \alpha^2(3A^2 +18A + 27) +(12A^2 +40A + 40) \iff$

$\frac {8A^2 + 44A+60}{3A^2+18A+27} - \frac 1{\alpha}\frac {12A^2 +40A + 40}{3A^2+18A+27} > \alpha$.

So this will be false whenever $\alpha \ge \frac {8A^2 + 44A+60}{3A^2+18A+27} - \frac 1{\alpha}\frac {12A^2 +40A + 40}{3A^2+18A+27}$ which will include (but not be restricted to) whenever $\alpha \ge \frac {8A^2 + 44A+60}{3A^2+18A+27}$.

So....

For any $A > 0$ we can always find $\alpha \ge \frac {8A^2 + 44A+60}{3A^2+18A+27}$ is which case $\alpha (8A^2 + 44A+60) <  \alpha^2(3A^2 +18A + 27) +(12A^2 +40A + 40)$

====

Alternatively bases on achille hui's comment:

$8A^2\alpha+44A\alpha+60\alpha>3A^2\alpha^2+12A^2+18A\alpha^2+40A+27\alpha^2+40 \iff$

$0>-3A^2a^2 > (12A^2 + 18A\alpha^2 +40A + 27\alpha^2 +40) -(44A\alpha +60\alpha)$

It's pretty clear that if we take $A$ and $\alpha$ large enough we can find values where the RHS is positive.

For example: If we let $18A\alpha^2 > 44A\alpha$ or in other words let $\alpha > \frac {44}{18}=\frac {22}9$ we have:

$ (12A^2 + 18A\alpha^2 +40A + 27\alpha^2 +40) -(44A\alpha +60\alpha)>$

$(12A^2 + 44A\alpha +40A + 27\cdot \frac {22}{9}\alpha +40)-(44A\alpha +60\alpha)=$

$12A^2  +40A + 66\alpha +40)-60\alpha=$

$12A^2 + 40A + 6\alpha + 40$

Which clearly positive.