# Given system of inequalities, how to determine for what range of values they are satisfied?

Tags: inequality, optimization, algorithms

Given equations: 
\begin{equation}
F_1(\mathbf{x}, \alpha) > 0\\
F_2(\mathbf{x}, \alpha) >0 \\
F_3(\mathbf{x}, \alpha) >0 \\
\vdots \\
F_n(\mathbf{x}, \alpha) >0 \\
\end{equation}

How to determine whether the system of inequalities are infeasible for any $\alpha$ value? If it's feasible then there exists a union of upper and lower bounds.

$\alpha^* = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k} \{l_j<\alpha_j<u_j\}$

Looking for a "generic" procedure that will determine if $\alpha^*=\emptyset$

Here are the assumptions and more details:

- $F_1(\mathbf{x}, \alpha) ... F_n(\mathbf{x}, \alpha)$ are continous
- $\mathbf{x} \in R^{n-1}$
- $\alpha \in R$
- If this problem is to abstract, lets also limit the functions $F_i$ to $\mathbf{v}^TA_i\mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{v}= \begin{bmatrix}
             x_{1} \\
             x_{2} \\
             \vdots \\
             x_{n-1} \\
             \alpha
           \end{bmatrix}$ (polynomials)

In short, the input to the "algorithm" are the systems of inequalities and the solution is true or false.

Another question on top of this, is this a NP hard problem? It definitely seems like the certificate will run in poly time at the least (my first glance at it).

Comment: My first thought on this is to convert the inequalities to equalities by adding slack variables and then trying to solve the systems of equations instead of inequalities.